# How to hide Navbar in Login Component with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Recently I started learning React and my problem here is that I cannot hide Navbar when Im in Login page/component. I have a Router in `index.js` like this:

```
const routing = (
 <div>
  <NavBar />
  <Router>
   <div>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
     <Route path="/users/:id" component={Users} />
     <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
     <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
     <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} hideNavBar={true} />
     <Route component={Notfound} />
    </Switch>
   </div>
  </Router>
 </div>
)
ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

From the little search that I made most approaches were like inserting `<NavBar />` in every component and use a flag to hide it when im in Login. Is there any other way like modifying the above code simple and fast?

Comment: You need to have either a flag for login state or pass the router and check the current url.

Comment: You should build a function that checks if the user is logged in or not, and just put a condition to display or not the navbar and the login route.

Comment: Not really you could have restrict access to all other routes like below

Comment: @AminPaks I was thinking about the last approach you say, but how I pass the router and then check the current url? Any example?

Comment: Wrap the navbar with withRouter and you’ll have it from props

Comment: I think you say something like this -> https://medium.com/@sandip21/how-to-hide-navbar-footer-on-authentication-pages-in-reactjs-40714ee1ce48 @AminPaks

Comment: Yeah pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

Not really you could have restrict access to all other routes like below I suppose

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest }) => 
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authenticated ? <Container ><Component {...props} /> <Container /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
      />
};
```

Where you container has a header , maybe footer and takes a child prop (your component)

Answer (score 0):

There are better approaches for hiding the `NavBar`on authenticated routes, but if you want to hide it when it's on `foo` route, you could check the path name and decide to render it or not.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    return location.pathname == '/login' ? <YourNavBarComponents /> : null
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me or guide me which is/are the best practices for hiding the Navbar because I'm new to React?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to hide parts of the UI building with React is to not include the markup. In order to do NOT display parts relying on the authentication you should have a flag if the authentication has done and is successful.

For example you can build a component that share some context in order to check if the authentication flag is true and render the parts that must be available only to users who have logged in.

You can follow [this example](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-basic-react-authentication-e20a574d5e71) to see the details how to build that component.

Basically you have a component that wraps another component and based on some rules render its children or call a render prop:

```js
function Private({ shouldRender = false, children }) {
  return shouldRender
    ? children
    : null;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Application</h2>
      <Private><div>This part is hidden</div></Private>
      <Private shouldRender={true}><div>This part is <strong>available</strong></div></Private>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```